# Copying Title and paste it into Keywords (merging)

Tags: metadata

I would like to process a batch of jpeg and copy the Title into Keywords (by merging contents). I have installed ExifTool but I can't figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this recursively with ExifTool, assuming you have a directory structure containing only the files you want to operate on, is:

`exiftool -r '-Keywords+<Title' -ext jpg /absolute/path/to/top/directory`

This will *add* the contents of the Title tag to any existing content in the Keywords tag (I assume this is what you mean by "merging").

The strong quotes around the tag argument are needed for protecting the '<' character from being interpreted by the shell (on at least some, if not all, platforms).

Copying your files, or at least a first batch, to a test directory to operate on is a good idea, until you're sure things are working the way you expect, although by default ExifTool will create backups of your original files by adding '_original' to the filename.